# Best approach to achieve guaranteed repeating background work Android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I'm in the process of developing an app which would mainly just be doing background work to read data from a nearby BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) sensor every 15 minutes (if Bluetooth is not switched on, it'll need to prompt the user to switch it on from the background service) and sync the data into the server once a day. I'm not sure of which approach would be most suited to do the background work as I need to have guaranteed timely execution of the background tasks as that's very critical to the purpose of the app.

I've looked at the following approaches:

- Using a ServiceIntent instant with a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. But I found out that WakefulBroadcastReceiver has been deprecated and there has been more restrictions to run background work since Android O.
- AlarmManager
- JobScheduler
- WorkManager (seems to be a good candidate but it's still in alpha and It doesn't seem to be production ready)

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: JobScheduler is the option if you are not confident with WorkManager in alpha.

Comment: Well the WorkManager is the best solution I have tried for background job but as you said it still in alpha, so go for JobScheduler

Comment: @OussemaAroua But do you think there's a tweak around to have guaranteed timely (every 15 minutes) execution of my background task with JobScheduler baring in mind the restrictions on background services introduces in version 6.0 with Doze mode and App standby?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use WorkManager even in alpha. I am alredy use it for similar task and it works. First time i started to use it, there where crashes, but after new version become released no more crashes occurs. Google provide a good support to its library, so use WorkManager since its the best option for background tasks execution.